Web Scraping - No proper page navigation output
When working with BeautifulSoup Python library to work in Data scraping for Amazon Reviews, I get no output when I change pages i.e &pageNumber=3 etc.

As in the image we can see that same page contents repeat or sometimes no content comes up.
Tried sample code from open source codes.
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
  'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8',
  'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="102", "Google Chrome";v="102"',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

reviews_url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Legendary-Whitetails-Journeyman-Jacket-Tarmac/product-reviews/B013KW38RQ/'

len_page = 3

def reviewsHtml(url, len_page):
  soups = []
  for page_no in range(1, len_page + 1):
    params = {
        'ie': 'UTF8',
        'reviewerType': 'all_reviews',
        'filterByStar': 'critical',
        'pageNumber': page_no,
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    soups.append(soup)
  return soups

def getReviews(html_data):
  data_dicts = []
  boxes = html_data.select('div[data-hook="review"]')
  for box in boxes:
    try:
      title = box.select_one('[data-hook="review-title"]').text.strip()
    except Exception as e:
      title = 'N/A'
    try:
      description = box.select_one('[data-hook="review-body"]').text.strip()
    except Exception as e:
      description = 'N/A'
    data_dict = {
      'Title' : title,
      'Description' : description
    }
    data_dicts.append(data_dict)
  return data_dicts

reviews = []
html_datas = reviewsHtml(reviews_url, len_page)
for html_data in html_datas:
  review = getReviews(html_data)
  reviews += review

df_reviews = pd.DataFrame(reviews)
df_reviews


you forgot params in line requests.get(... , params=params). And maybe it is the only problem.

I checked code with requests.get(... , params=params) and it gives reviews from other pages. Silly mistake :)

You're not using the params variable which is the dictionary that handles the page number. Consider including it in the request if the issue persists.
Check the URLs that are repeating manually by going to the website. Do they repeat in the actual site? If they don't really repeat and the content is different than the scraped content, consider debugging your code. If they do actually repeat, I would suggest making a hash for each page and each time you scrape a page compare to the scraped pages hashes; if they're identical, just ignore the page and move to the next one.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
